# Converter String com AM/PM para DateTime

Tags: c#, .net, string, datetime

Tenho uma variável que contém uma data com AM/PM:

```
string data = "01/08/2016 9:00 PM";
```

Quando tento converter para `DateTime` utilizando o método `TryParse` o resultado ignora o designador "AM/PM".

```
string data = "01/08/2016 9:00 PM";
DateTime dataOut;
if(DateTime.TryParse(data, out dataOut))
{
   //Restante do código.
   dataOut.ToString(); //Retorna 01/08/2016 09:00, deveria retornar 21:00.
}
```

Como prosseguir? Qual o método que utilizo para realizar essa conversão, levando em consideração o AM/PM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Talvez seja o caso para usar [`TryParseExact()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_DateTime_TryParseExact_System_String_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_System_Globalization_DateTimeStyles_System_DateTime__) e definir o formato que vai verificar (coloquei um formato, não sei se é o mais adequado pra você):

```
using System;
using static System.Console;
using System.Globalization;
                    
public class Program {
    public static void Main(){
        var data = "01/08/2016 9:00 PM";
        DateTime dataOut;
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(data, "MM/dd/yyyy h:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dataOut)) {
            WriteLine(dataOut.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"));
        }
        data = "01/08/2016 9:00 AM";
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(data, "MM/dd/yyyy h:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dataOut)) {
            WriteLine(dataOut.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"));
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/llfS3l). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/82gCJV). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/DateTime/ParseExactCulture.cs).

Answer (score 2):

Use o [formato `HH`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx?f=255&mspperror=-2147217396#Anchor_22):

> O formato `HH` representa a hora como um número de *00* a *23*; a
>   hora é representada por um relógio de *24* horas com base em zero que
>   conta as horas desde a meia-noite. A hora de dígito único é formatado
>   com um zero à esquerda.

Código:

```
string data1 = "01/08/2016 9:00 AM";
string data2 = "01/08/2016 9:00 PM";

DateTime dataOut;

if(DateTime.TryParse(data1, out dataOut)) {
    Console.WriteLine(dataOut.ToString("HH:mm ", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)); // 09:00
}

if(DateTime.TryParse(data2, out dataOut)) {
    Console.WriteLine(dataOut.ToString("HH:mm ", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)); // 21:00
}
```

<kbd>[Ver **DEMO**](http://ideone.com/eqUyF4)</kbd>